# How to make WebSocket Secure (wss) connections in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Is there any way i can upgrade the websocket connection from a fastapi server from ws:// to wss://. When I try to connect using the wss protocol in my api tester, it just fails but the ws protocol works

Comment: Have you configured TLS/SSL in any way? Unless you set up and configure SSL you're not going to be able to serve content as `wss`: https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-with-https - if you're using uvicorn. You can also configure tls/https with nginx and use that in front of your FastAPI instance

Comment: Hi, @MatsLindh, I really havent configured TLS/SSL in any way, I looked through the docs and that probably has given me a idea, thanks for showing the way